# R clarification of the meaning of the formula

Tags: r, function

I have code:

```
x1=rnorm(100,-10,1)
sum(x1>quantile(x1,0.05))/length(x1)
```

What exactly the second line of code does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x1 is 100 normally distributed #s from a population with mean of -10.

`quantile(x1,0.05)` identifies the 5th percentile of that vector.

`x1>quantile(x1,0.05)` tests each element in x1 to see if it's more than that 5th percentile, outputting TRUE (aka 1) if so, so its sum is a count of elements larger than the 5th percentile.

Finally, it's divided by the number of elements in x1: 100. So we're checking what percentage of the values are more than the 5th percentile. I'd expect 95%.

Comment: So if, for example, I reverse sum (x1 <quantile (x1,0.05)) / length (x1) then it will give me 5% right?

Comment: Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: Yes, and you can run that to confirm.

Comment: The 2nd line is equivalent to the simpler and easier to understand `mean(x1>quantile(x1,0.05))`. Upvote.

Comment: Thank you user438383 for editing my post